# asp.net mvc Hide column used for filter

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i have a table that i filter using a checkbox based on a column field bool "isAdmin" - when checkbox is checked, i see all orders, when unchecked,
i only see orders with isAdmin = true.
this is working as expected,
but i want isAdmin (first column) to be hidden, but i can't remove it since
i want to use it for the filtering.
View Html:

```
<table id="tblData" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
        <div id="AllOrders">
            <input type="checkbox" id="pos" value=true />  Show All Orders
        </div>
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr class="table-info">
                <th>Is Admin</th>
                <th>Order Id</th>
                <th>Order Status</th>
                <th>Product</th>
                <th>US Date</th>
                <th>Store</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Full Address</th>
                <th>Tracking Number</th>
                <th></th>
        </thead>
        @{string FullAddress = "";}
        @foreach (Order order in Model.Order)
        {
            FullAddress = "";
    <tr>
        <td>@order.IsAdmin</td>
        <td>@order.Id</td>
        <td>@order.OrderStatus</td>
        .
        .
        .
        .
    </table>
```

Javascript that control the checkbox in the section script:

```
<script>
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
        function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
            var isAdmin = data[0];
            if ($('#pos').prop("checked") == true) {
                return true;
            } else if ($('#pos').prop("checked") == false && isAdmin) {
                return true;
            }
            else { return false; }
        }
    );
    $('input:checkbox').on('change', function () {
        var table = $('#tblData').DataTable();
        table.draw();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: please be more specific, do you want to show orders where isAdmin=true ? How do you want to filter it? What is the outcome you expect?

Comment: Hi, 
i edit the post. basically, it is already working i just want to hide the first column isAdmin and still use it for the filtering.

Comment: Wrap the contents in a span and hide it. Set the column width to 1px.

Comment: <td><span width="1px">@order.IsAdmin</span></td>
tried this, nothing changed...

Comment: You can add a data attribute to`<tr>` like `<tr data-admin=true> all <td> goes here </tr>` then you simply filter rows where `data-admin is true`

Comment: `<td style="width:1px"><span style="display:none">@order.IsAdmin</span></td>`